# Kullback–Leibler divergence of two multivariate normal distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I have a problem: I want to calculate Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence of two dataset where $X_{1}$ has $M$ features with its multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $X_{2}$ have $M$ features with its multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$ random sample from one large dataset. I found that someone asked for a calculation of KL divergence for two univariate normal distributions in:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians

that have resulted of KL divergence: [KL divergence of two univariate Gaussian distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQYCG.png)

How could I map this result for two multivariate normal distributions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p\sim\mathcal N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $q\sim\mathcal N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$ both of dimension $k$ (and both $\Sigma_i$ can be inverted) then

\begin{align*}
\log p(x) = -\frac{k}{2} \log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\log(\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_1)) - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (x-\mu_1)\\
\log q(x) = -\frac{k}{2} \log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log(\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_2)) - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_2)
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{KL}(p\|q)&=\mathbb E[\log p(X) - \log q(X)]
\end{align*}

Where the expectation is on $X\sim p$.

Now, using a nice little trick with traces you get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[(X-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (X-\mu_1)]
&=\mathbb E[\operatorname{Tr}((X-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (X-\mu_1))]\\
&=\mathbb E[\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_1^{-1} (X-\mu_1)(X-\mu_1)^T)]\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbb E[(X-\mu_1)(X-\mu_1)^T])\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_1^{-1} \Sigma_1)\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(I_k)\\
&=k
\end{align*}

we further have
\begin{align*}
&(x-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_2) \\=& (x-\mu_1+\mu_1-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_1+\mu_1-\mu_2)\\
=&(x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_1) + 2 (\mu_1-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_1) + (\mu_1-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_2)
\end{align*}
therefore by the same trick with the trace as before we get
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb E[(X-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (X-\mu_2)]\\
= &\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1) + 2\cdot 0 + (\mu_1-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_2)\\
= &\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1) + 2\cdot 0 + \operatorname{Tr}((\mu_1-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_2))\\
= &\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1) + 2\cdot 0 + \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_2)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^T)\\
= &\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}(\Sigma_1+ (\mu_1-\mu_2)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^T))\\
\end{align*}

Putting things together yields
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{KL}(p\|q)\\
=&\mathbb E[-\frac{k}{2} \log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\log(\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_1)) - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (x-\mu_1)]\\
&-\mathbb E[-\frac{k}{2} \log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log(\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_2)) - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (x-\mu_2)]\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_2)}{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_1)}\right) - \frac k2 + \frac12\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}(\Sigma_1+ (\mu_1-\mu_2)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^T))\\
\end{align*}

In your case $\Sigma_i=\sigma_i^2 I$, therefore
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{KL}(p\|q)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{k\sigma_2^2}{k\sigma_1^2}\right) - \frac k2 + \frac{k\sigma_1^2+\operatorname{Tr}((\mu_1-\mu_2)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^T)}{2\sigma_2^2}\\
=&\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right) - \frac k2 + \frac{k\sigma_1^2+\| \mu_1-\mu_2\|^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for providing your insightful response. I am seeking clarification on a specific scenario involving multivariate normal distributions. If the location of two multivariate normal distributions, denoted as $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, are equal ($\mu_1 = \mu_2$), but the covariances, represented by $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, are not equal ($\Sigma_1 \neq \Sigma_2$), how does this difference in covariance impact the KL divergence between these distributions?

Comment: If you look at the general expression, only $\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_2)}{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_1)}\right) - \frac k2 + \frac12\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_2^{-1}(\Sigma_1))$ remains. Without knowing more about your setup it will be hard for me to say much more. But a usual case is that $\Sigma_2$ is the diagonal matrix made of the diagonal elements of $\Sigma_1$, this is some multivariate generalization of the mutual information between $k$ random variable.